# Sorting a string list first alphabetically then numerically

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

So I have a List of objects that has a property with the type string. I want the object to be sorted by that property. The problem is the following:
The List looks like something like this

```
12 Apple 
43 Banana
22 Apple 
90 Banana
13 Banana
67 Apple
```

I want the list to be sorted like the following:

```
12 Apple
22 Apple
67 Apple
13 Banana
43 Banana
90 Banana
```

I was experimenting a bit and I was trying to accomplish it like this:

```
myList.Sort(x, y) => x.Value.Contains("Banana").CompareTo(x.Value.Contains("Banana");
```

Of couse this doesnt work.
Anyone knows how to accomplish that

Comment: Well you're close; you just need to remove the `Contains("Banana")` thing.

Comment: Why not using `OrderBy` like this?  `myList.OrderBy(c => c.fruitName).ThenBy(c => c.fruitId).ToList()`?

Comment: Are the numbers and the string values separate properties? Because that would make it _real_ easy. Otherwise I'm guessing you're going to need to split the strings and get the numbers separate from the fruits.

Comment: Question is unclear.. in your example.. is `12 Apple` all 1 string, or is it `12` `Apple` as 2 separate properties (int, string / string, string)?

Comment: Your title conflicts with your expected output. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Please provide syntactically correct code in your question. The parentheses of your sort code are not adding up to a valid statement.

Comment: @J.Steen maybe he's talking about 2 times full sort with a stable sort algorithm... would preserve the sorted IDs in group...

Comment: ask a clear and concise question and not a puzzle. Till then voting to close

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ:

```
var orderedFruits = fruitList.OrderBy(f => f.Value).ThenBy(f => f.FruitId);
```

If you want it to be a list again:

```
fruitList = orderedFruits.ToList();
```

---

Well, if the string property actually contains the number and the fruit-name it's more complicated and it would be better to repair your class by storing both informations in separate properties.

However:

```
var orderedFruits = fruitList
   .Select(f => new { arr = f.Value.Split(), OriginalFruit = f })
   .Where(x => x.arr[0].Trim().All(char.IsDigit))
   .Select(x => new { ID = int.Parse(x.arr[0].Trim()), Fruit = x.arr.Last().Trim(), x.OriginalFruit })
   .OrderBy(x => x.Fruit)
   .ThenBy(x => x.ID)
   .Select(x => x.OriginalFruit);
```

Comment: confusing ... cause this is correct but as OP says *List of objects that has a property with the type string. I want the object to be sorted by that property.* so the interpretation was `12 Apple` is a whole string

Comment: @Rahul: hmm, you're right, maybe. Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Tim, not sure am right or wrong but that's my interpretation and kind a guess ... cause the question itself in damn confusing.

Comment: @Rahul: interesting, as soon as i'm providing a more detailed answer covering both cases it's downvoted. I'm curious about the reason :)

Comment: Tim, it's not me at all but don't see any reason for the answer to be downvoted though. Your edit made the answer much detailed

Comment: @TimSchmelter +1, but that last snippet seems a bit Rube Goldberg-esque. Wouldn't `fruitList.OrderBy(f => f.Split()[1].Trim())` work? If OP needs more rigorous parsing they should probably just write a `Func<string, ParsedType>` and `fruitList.Select` over that.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin:  If OP wants to sort by the fruit-name first and then by the number, you have to split both, then you have to parse the numeric part to integer and use `OrderBy...ThenBy`. look at the desired order and the original order. The numeric sort seems to be important, otherwise `13 Banana` wouldn't come first in the second group.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
 var orderfruitlist = fruitslist.OrderBy(x => x.Fruit.Split(' ')[1]).ThenBy(x => x.Fruit.Split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: However, you are doing the rather heavy-weight task of the `Split()` *twice*

Comment: Doesn't handle some edge cases, f.e. no space in `Value`, doesn't sort numerically but alphanumerically, so `100` comes before `99`.

Answer (score 0):

Now, assuming that (a) "12 Apple" is one string, and (b) the title of the question is wrong and you actually want to sort first on words, THEN by the number, this wouldn't be that hard -- assuming that all the numbers are 2-digit:

```
var sorted = from f in fruitlist
           orderby f.Substring(3), f
           select f;
```

Now, if the number can be more or less than 2 digits, then we've got to get a bit more involved:
(Updated to do a proper numeric sort)

```
var sorted = from f in fruitlist
           let parts = f.Split(' ')
           orderby parts[1], Int32.Parse(parts[0])
           select f;
```

Comment: Ok, so the other answers assume a numeric *other* property - possibly wrong assumption but would work. This is doing a string sort on the numeric part which will give a very non-numeric sort order.

Comment: Well, a string sort of a 2-digit number will work.  I'll need to fix the second version.